# Random walk on non-abelian free group

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, gr.group-theory, graph-theory

Let $F_2$ be the free non-abelian group with generators $a, b\in F_2$.

Has the "random walk" where we start with the identity and then multiply it by $a$ or $b$ or $a^{-1}$ or $b^{-1}$ studied in the literature? Are there any books on it?

Also what about the random walk on the set of finite strings consisting of characters 'a' and 'b' where we start with the empty string then either append a character or remove a character?

Comment: These are really just random walks on trees - the former corresponds to a regular tree of degree 4, the latter to the full (rooted) binary tree.

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of literature on random walks on finitely generated groups.  For instance see some work by [Laurent Saloff-Coste](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~lsc/avpub.html).  What kind of results would you be looking for?

Comment: Look at theorem 3 of https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1959-092-02/S0002-9947-1959-0109367-6/S0002-9947-1959-0109367-6.pdf

Comment: Title of @BenjaminSteinberg's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390690/random-walk-on-non-abelian-free-group#comment995932_390690):  [Kester - Symmetric random walks on groups](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1959-0109367-6).